# Determine if numeric type A can be cast to numeric type B

Tags: c++, types, casting, c++11

Given two numeric types `From` and `To`. Does the following code actually determine whether or not any value of type `From` can be represented as a value of type `To` without losing information? If yes, is there a shorter or more readable way of determining?

```
template <class From, class To>
struct can_cast
{
    static const bool value = 
        (std::numeric_limits<From>::is_integer || // either From is an integer type OR 
        std::is_floating_point<To>::value) && // ...they're both floating point types AND
        (std::numeric_limits<From>::is_signed == false || // either From is unsigned OR
        std::numeric_limits<To>::is_signed == true) && // ...they're both signed AND
        (std::numeric_limits<From>::digits < std::numeric_limits<To>::digits || // To has more bits for digits than From OR
        std::numeric_limits<From>::digits == std::numeric_limits<To>::digits && // To and From have same number of bits, but
        std::numeric_limits<From>::is_signed == std::numeric_limits<To>::is_signed); // they're either both signed or both unsigned.
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has this feature built-in now: narrowing conversions are not allowed when using list-initialisation.

You can write a traditional expression tester trait based off of `To { std::declval<From>() }` and possibly add additional checks with `std::is_integral` and `std::is_floating_point`.

```
template <typename T>
struct sfinae_true : std::true_type {};

struct can_cast_tester {
   template <typename From, typename To>
   sfinae_true<decltype(To { std::declval<From>() })> static test(int);
   template <typename...>
   std::false_type static test(...);
}; 

template <typename From, typename To>
struct can_cast // terrible name
: decltype(can_cast_tester::test<From, To>(0)) {};
```

Theoretically, this should work, but currently it seems neither GCC nor clang get it right.

Comment: Well, if you try `int x{1.5};` in gcc-4.7.1 it only reports a warning, not an error as it should.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Debatable. The Standard only cares about 'diagnostics' and a GCC user can decide to turn those warnings into errors if they so desire. The GCC documentation for e.g. `-pedantic` mentions: "Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO C++". At worst it's a GCC usability/consistency issue, and more of a bikeshed really.

Comment: @Maxim: With `-Wnarrowing` you get an error, atleast [on LWS](http://liveworkspace.org/code/e25b20e376589681abd3d5c0e8395885) I do.

Comment: @Xeo: `-Wnarrowing` just enables the warning, you probably meant `-Werror=narrowing` to turn it into an error.

Comment: @LucDanton: Fair enough. On the other hand, gcc-4.7.1 behaviour precludes using `SFINAE` for this case.

Comment: @Maxim: Maybe, I don't know if LWS does that. :/ In any case, you can get an error from it, somehow.